# Wemos - oled sparkfun print text does not display

Tags: text, printing, arduino

I'm using a led matrix shield (http://www.wemos.cc/Products/oled_shield.html) with a wemos. I'm using Arduino IDE.
The exemples work perfectly (https://github.com/wemos/D1_mini_Examples/tree/master/04.Shields/OLED_Shield/Use_SparkFun_Library)

But when I try to print text, the screen remains empty. Here is my code

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <SFE_MicroOLED.h>  // Include the SFE_MicroOLED library


#define PIN_RESET 255
#define DC_JUMPER 0


MicroOLED oled(PIN_RESET, DC_JUMPER);

void setup()
{
  oled.begin();
  oled.clear(ALL);
  oled.clear(PAGE);
  oled.display(); 

  oled.setFontType(0);
  oled.setCursor(0, 0);
  oled.print("Hello, world");
  oled.display();
}

void loop()
{ 
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue. I modified SFE_MicroOLED lib.
The fonts are loaded in the program memory (via PROGMEM directive). This makes the code fail on wemos.
I remove PROGMEM directive on a fork of this lib (https://github.com/landru29/SparkFun_Micro_OLED_Arduino_Library)

I just check if the arch is ARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU
https://github.com/landru29/SparkFun_Micro_OLED_Arduino_Library/blob/master/src/util/7segment.h#L37 (idem for all other font files in the same folder)